# PagedListHolder sorted by multiple properties

Tags: spring, sorting

I want to implement a pagination using spring PagedListHolder. I see it's using MutableSortDefinition implemented from SortDefinition. but this MutableSortDefinition only sort by one property. what I want to do is sort by two properties. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

I'm thinking write my own class implementing SortDefinition. but I see the MutableSortDefintion only has a equal() method. how would this method do sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot sort on two fields simultaneously. You need to prioritize the sorting order on each field in the class being held inpagelistholder.
For eg., sort on fields  {[ac,ef],[ab,ad],[ab,bc]} sorting in ascending order on this will lead to {[ab,ad],[ab,bc],[ac,ef]} (If first field is same(in eg., ab), then compare on second field).
Suppose a class have 2 fields on which sorting needs to be performed:

```
    public class MyClass{
        private String field1; //First priority
        private String field2; //Second priority
        ...
    }
```

Implement a comparator on this class as:

```
    public class MyClassComparator implements Comparator<MyClass>{
        @Override
        public int compare(MyClass m1, MyClass m2){
            int compareResult = m1.getField1().compareIgnoreCase(m2.getField1());
            if(compareResult != 0){ //i.e., two field1 are different
                return compareResult;
            }else{//i.e., compare on two field2 and return the result
                return m1.getField2().compareIgnoreCase(m2.getField2());
            }
        }
    }
```

To sort and pass it to pagelistholder in your method:

```
    //list of Myclass is in myClassList     
    //myClassComparator is instance of MyClassComparator
    Collections.sort(myClassList, myClassComparator);
    PagedListHolder holder = new PagedListHolder<MyClass>(myClassList);
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful tips. I created my own ApsPropertyComparator.java. I copied the src code of PropertyComparator.java and modify the method compare();

Comment: I also created my own ApsPagedListHolder.java extends PagedListHolder.java override the method doSort() which will be calling my own comparator. :)

Comment: do you care to share your implementations?